# Validity of my database model

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, relational-database

Before this design, my database model didnt have `orderProducts` which meant that there was a many to many relationship between `products` and `orders` as all of the fields in 'orderProducts' were in orders.. Have I resolved this properly using the junction table? Also I am unsure how to associate the `userType` table with the tables. Thanks.
[image]

Comment: Not sure how you would Join the 'UserType' if there isn't another field that is identical to it, like a foreign key relationship for example. The UserID needs to be in the OrderProducts table or one of the related tables in order to work correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resolution with the orderProducts table makes good sense, though you can leave productName out of it (since that can come from the Product table) to reduce data redundancy. Likewise, price can be in the product table.

As for relating users to the existing tables, consider the relation between users and orders - presumably each user can have multiple orders, but each order will only have one user, so you have a one-to-many relationship from user to order, and can have user_ID as a FK in the order table.

Comment: Thanks @Stidgeon this has helped me alot.

Answer (score 0):

Add something like the UserID into the orderProducts Table then you should be able to use SQL JOIN as needed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As Stidgeon says, you need to add userID to your order table. Since orderID is unique, you can have many orders per user. You don't need to bridge these tables.

Your userType table appears to be a lookup table and should have a userTypeID field as a primary key, not the userID. Then add a UserTypeID field as a foreign key to your user table.

Please be aware that table names should be singular (user, order, etc.)